# Can I use this attentuator to attentuate a passive stage monitor

Tags: speakers

[image]

I have a power amp that connects to a passive monitor which connects to a second passive monitor (I don't know if saying they're connected in series is the right terminology). I'd like to attentuate the second monitor without changing the volume of the other, so I figured putting an attentuator in between the two that can pass power may work. But as I don't want to waste money/damage equipment, I'm asking for a second opinion. Would connecting this in between work?

If not, how can I make the second monitor quieter than the first?

Shure A15AS Switchable Attenuator (15, 20, 25 dB), Passes Phantom Power https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B0002J1JKY/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_wpPyzbXXG21T8

Comment: That attenuator is meant for small signals, line level or microphone level.  It isn't going to be happy connected to the output of a power amplifier.

Comment: Short answer: nope.

Answer (score 1):

No, that attenuator will not work. It's designed to connect to a mic, which will push out a very small electrical signal compared with that of an amp going to a speaker. That apart, with XLRs, chances are it won't fit physically.

To attenuate the signal, you are going to need something bigger that will dissipate heat produced while trying to sap the power to that speaker. It's possible with a big pot., which will do that and be adjustable, too.

A far more workable system is to either use a speaket with a high impedence - but watch the overall impedence match to the amp., or use another mixer/amp to feed that speaker. A lot of mixer amps will already have the facility to re-mix signals to another monitor/powered monitor.